# XCODE - How to update array?

Tags: xcode, arrays, xcode4, nsmutablearray, logic

I'm very new to Xcode/programming and trying to modify existing code

I'm having a small problem where I have an amount of objects (enemies) on the screen at one particular time and cannot redefine their value. I set my enemies to begin with 3 on the screen.

My objective is to change the amount of enemies based on the current score.

I've attached snippets of the code below.

```
int numberOfEnemies;

if (self.score>=0) {
numberOfEnemies = 3
}

else if (self.score>=100) {
numberOfEnemies = 4
}


// Setup array 

enemyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfEnemies; i++) {
    [enemyArray addObject:[SpriteHelpers setupAnimatedSprite:self.view numFrames:3
    withFilePrefix:@"enemyicon" withDuration:((CGFloat)(arc4random()%2)/3 + 0.5)
    ofType:@"png" withValue:0]];
}

enemyView = [enemyArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

What do I need to do to parse the new value of `numberOfEnemies` into the array when my score updates?

Comment: which array? I think that you'll need to show a a bit more code.

Comment: The code youre showing now is that in some kind of an update function? What is the size of the array containing your enemies? I'm guessing you reuse them, or are they currently just static/non interactive?

Comment: @pb2q please see update array component. Hope this helps

Comment: What function is the above code in is what I'm asking. Does it get run more than once? If it does, your code should work based on what you've provided. If it doesn't what are the errors/bad behavior you are seeing?

Comment: @KarolyS Hi Karoly are you suggesting i create and update function? I've added some more code if this helps

Comment: What don't you know how to do? You show code for adding additional enemies to your array.

Comment: Yes, you should have a game update loop right? If you want the number of enemies to be dynamic you need to put the generate enemy code into a function, lets say called generateEnemy, and then call it inside of your update function. Chances are you are only running the above code once, which means any changes in your score will not be captured, which is why you are more than likely only getting 3 enemies.

Comment: Oh its currently in viewdidload. I'll try moving to a a function underneath.

Comment: @KarolyS Hi Karoly, i'm not having much luck. You were right about only getting three enemies. The generate enemy takes places at viewdidload. I tried to create an update function after view did load to update the enemies but to no avail. Could you please provide an example of an update game loop?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to move our conversation into an answer since I don't want it to get too long winded, and I can easily edit and expand on this.

So far, we've established that the reason that you're having issues is that you execute the above code in the viewDidLoad function, which will run at least once when the application is first started. The problem with this is as you've found out, that you arent getting a chance to see a new score, and then update the number of enemies.

I know that game update loops for iOS are usually done in the following structure, but I would recommend finding a tutorial online to get what may be a more efficient/correct way to do it.

From your current structure, I would take the code you have above and create a new function out of it:

```
-(void) updateDifficulty:(NSTimer *)gameTimer
{
    //This can be the code you have above for now
}
```

Afterwards, inside of your viewDidLoad, I would put the following code:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad:
{
    gameTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateDifficulty:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:gameTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}
```

What that does is it declares a timer that will keep track of the game time, and with how it was declared, every 1 second it will call the updateDifficulty method. This is the general structure that you want, but again I would highly suggest you check out a game tutorial from Ray Wenderlich for example.

Hope that helps!